# Why doesn't g++ find the precompiled-header that's in the -I include-path?

Tags: g++, precompiled-headers, pch

I'm trying to build a precompiled header and an executable, like so:

```sh
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++17 \
    -c ./src/pch.hpp -o ./build/pch.hpp.gch

g++ -g -Wall -std=c++17 \
        -c ./src/*.cpp  \
        -I./build/ -include pch.hpp
```

The `pch.hpp.gch` file is created correctly. But for each of the `.cpp` files, I'm getting the following error:

```
1 error generated.
<built-in>:1:10: fatal error: 'pch.hpp' file not found
#include "pch.hpp"
```

---

I think my compilation line is correct, based on the [gcc Precompiled Headers documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html):

- `-I./build/` tells it to add `build` directory to the include search-path.
- `-include pch.hpp` prepends an `#include <pch.hpp>` directive to each file.
- The compiler searches for precompiled headers, with the `.gch` suffix, for each of its `#include` directives.

**Why is my compilation line not working as expected?**

---

There are some things I've tried which *do* give me better results, but they don't look correct to me.

**If I modify the include to search for a .gch file, then the file is found,** in line with what I'd expect. That is, `-include pch.hpp.gch`, instead of `-include pch.hpp` .
But then, the PCH is interpreted as a binary file, and compilation fails:

```
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++17 \
        -c ./src/*.cpp  \
        -I./build/ -include pch.hpp.gch
./build/pch.hpp.gch:2:22: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
```

I'm not surprised that `#include <pch.hpp.gch>` doesn't compile. But I'm mentioning this since it seems to show that in my original command, the `build` folder is searched (as I expected), but the mechanism that knows to use the `.gch` file instead of a regular header isn't active. Weird.

Alternatively, **if I add the `src` folder to the header search path, it works:**

```
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++17 \
        -c ./src/*.cpp  \
        -I./src/ -I./build/ -include pch.hpp
```

I do not understand why adding *another*, irrelevant include-path solves anything. Weird.

---

My current working solution is to drop the `-I` include-path directive entirely, and **specify a more complete path to `build/pch.hpp`**:

```
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++17 \
        -c ./src/*.cpp  \
        -include ./build/pch.hpp
```

This one works as expected. I'm not sure why it's necessary, though, and it's peculiar and inconvenient.

Is this how a PCH is supposed to be used? Why does my original line not work, and what am I meant to be doing instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html):

> A precompiled header file is searched for when #include is seen in the compilation. As it searches for the included file (see Search Path in The C Preprocessor) the compiler looks for a precompiled header in each directory just before it looks for the include file in that directory. The name searched for is the name specified in the #include with ‘.gch’ appended. If the precompiled header file cannot be used, it is ignored.
>
> For instance, if you have `#include "all.h"`, and you have all.h.gch in the same directory as all.h, then the precompiled header file is used if possible, and the original header is used otherwise.

It means that the compiler must be able to find BOTH h-file and gch-file while building cpp. So they BOTH should in the same directory or the same include search path.

Comment: So why when I use
-include ./build/pch.hpp
without the additional search path the compiler will not find the original header file, and yet it still works?

Comment: Your second option is skipping precompiled header at all. Compiler includes pch.hpp as a typical header file.